# Erro em uma função que retorna uma AND de duas variáveis em python

Tags: python, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo, int, booleano

Fiz uma função em Python que em teoria deve retornar uma `and` de cada elemento de duas variáveis, porém o resultado não está sendo o esperado.

A resposta seria `[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]`, mas está retornando `[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]`, que é o valor de `b`

```
a = "11001100"
b = "01101100"

def p_and(a,b):
  aux=[]
  for i in range(8):
    aux.append(int(a[i] and b[i]))
  return aux
```

Comment: `map(int, format(int(a, 2) & int(b, 2), 'b'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

è o mesmo problema da sua pergunta anterior, portanto não aprendeu com a solução lá., você tem que que converter os valores individualmente para aplicar o operador, está aplicando o operador no valor não convertido e depois faz a conversão do resultado que já está errado.

```
a = "11001100"
b = "01101100"
def p_and(a,b):
    aux=[]
    for i in range(8):
        aux.append(int(a[i]) and int(b[i]))
    return aux
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nCR6w0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ConvertIntpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/ConvertInt.py).

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "11001100"
b = "01101100"

def p_and(a,b):
  aux=[]
  for i in range(8):
    aux.append(int(int(a[i]) and int(b[i])))
  return aux

print (p_and(a,b))
```

Comment: É o mesmo código da outra resposta, a exceção do `print`. Em que essa resposta acrescenta aos usuários? Se tiver dúvidas sobre como responder, leia [answer]. Se tiver dúvidas sobre o funcionamento da página faça o nosso [tour].

Comment: Não havia outra resposta quando eu enviei a minha. Se é igual, coincidência. Não tive tempo de comentar o código pois tive que sair do computador. Eu iria retornar e editar a resposta. Mas ok.